# Behavior of EM waves in general relativity

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, gravity, waves

I've created an account for the sole purpose of asking this questions.
Bear in mind, I'm no physicist nor a student, I've just recently gained interest in physics by realizing the vast amount of questions it answers with its precise mathematical modeling.

As much as I understood, according to General Relativity, mass curves space-time where it is that curvature that we experience as gravity.
Yet again, Einstein postulated that $E=mc^2$, therefore electromagnetic waves, massless as they are, should curve the space-time as well because of their energy, especially considering high energy waves, such as x-rays and gamma-rays.

If I've got that right, my question then is:

How do EM waves behave under the influence of their own gravity? Is it to be deduced, that if I'm not too wrong, that depending on their alignments between themselves there might occur destructive-constructive overlaps which we would then experience as constant change in intensity?

Of course, I imagined this to happen to waves in space whose behavior scientists are much more likely to observe.

Thanks in advance and I apologize if I made some catastrophic, uneducated guesses, I'm still in the learning process :)

Comment: "Einstein postulated that $e=mc^2$" misses the whole point.  This is not a postulate; it is a consequence derived from far more fundamental assumptions.